# How to setup blog page to render blog posts minus afew categories

Tags: query-posts, page-template

I have set my home page to use a static template. So I created a Blog page to use a blog template to render my blog posts. The problem is it just renders the page content. I want it to render blog posts. Minus that of category "portfolio" & "WIP". Do I need to create a custom `query_posts`? what might it look like. To simulate what I get by default if my home page is set to latest posts. I will also need pagination to work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to exclude categories then you do need to create a custom query
something like this:

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;    
query_posts( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) , 'paged' => $page ) );
```

just above the loop and change 2 , 6 to the category ids which you want to exclude , and to help keep pagination i would add `wp_reset_query();` just after the loop to save later problems.

keep in mind that this is probably the simplest form of the query_post you need but if you want more out of its power take a look at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

Hope This Helps

Comment: I saw the codex and actually wondered if I need to add `publish = true posttype = post` etc for example. They are the defaults but I wonder since its a page, and the `query_posts` looks more like `posttype=page&page=x` I need to re-specify the params

Comment: Also is there a way to exclude categories by nicenames not ids?